# Criar função de excluir em projeto em C

Tags: c

Criei um projeto de uma biblioteca escolar. Estou sem ideia para criar a função deletar:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 15

typedef struct TAutor {
    char Nome[40];
    char   Pais[20];
    char cidade[30];
    char isbn[25];
    int idade;
}Autor;

typedef struct Tlivro {
    char Nome_livro[20];
    Autor Nome_autor[20];
    char pais_local[30];
    char cidade_local[30];
    char isbn[25];
    int ano_lancamento;
}Livro;

 void ver_vazio(Livro cadas_livro[MAX]);
    void inserir();
    void listar();
    void eliminar();

main()
{   int opc=0,cont=0,fim=0,men=1,sair=0,pin=0,i=0;

    Livro cadas_livro[MAX];
    printf("\t########################################################\n");
    printf("\t###       Gestao da biblioteca                 ###\n");
    printf("\t########################################################\n");
    printf("\t###        [1]->Inserir Dados no Sitema              ###\n");
    printf("\t###        [2]->Ver Dados no Sistema               ###\n");
    printf("\t###                                                  ###\n");
    printf("\t###                                                  ###\n");
    printf("\t###                                                  ###\n");
    printf("\t########################################################\n");
    printf(" \n");

do{
    printf("\tEscolha a opcao:");
    scanf("%d",&opc);
    fflush(stdin);

            switch(opc)
            {
                case 1:
                    do
                    {

                                  inserir();
                                system("cls");
                                 //este codi foi feito para aparecer apenas a pergunta será sempre falço se escolher esta opções
                                 printf("\n");
                                 puts("\tse pretende continuar[1] se nao[2]");
                                 scanf("%d",&fim);

                    }while(men==fim);break;
                       //inserir();break;
                          //  men=getch();
                            //while(men=getch())


                case 2:
                    printf("\n");
                listar();break;
                default :printf("Esta opcao nao existe");
            }
    printf("\n");
    printf("\tOpcao do menu Continuar[1]-Sair[0]");
    scanf("%d",&sair);
}while(sair==1);

}
//função inserir
void inserir()

{   Livro cadas_livro[MAX];
    int i=0;
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\tInsira o nome do livro: ");
    fgets(cadas_livro[i].Nome_livro,20,stdin);
    printf("\tInsira o nome do autor: ");
    fgets(cadas_livro[i].Nome_autor[i].Nome,40,stdin);
    printf("\tPais de lancamento: ");
    fgets(cadas_livro[i].pais_local,30,stdin);
    printf("\tCidade de Lancamento: ");
    fgets(cadas_livro[i].cidade_local,30,stdin);
    printf("\tISbn:");
    fgets(cadas_livro[i].isbn,25,stdin);
    i++;

}

void listar(int dado)
{   fflush(stdin);
    Livro cadas_livro[MAX];
    int i=0;

        printf("\tNome do livro:%s ",cadas_livro[i].Nome_livro);
    printf("\tNome do autor:%s ",cadas_livro[i].Nome_autor[i].Nome);
    printf("\tCidade de Lancamento %s",cadas_livro[i].cidade_local);
    printf("\tPais de lancamento:%s ",cadas_livro[i].pais_local);
    printf("\tISbn:%s ",cadas_livro[i].isbn);



    printf(" \n");
    printf("\t\t\t\tSoftware Fabricado Pela Erms.system \n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t###################################\n");
}

void eliminar()
{ int i;
        Livro cadas_livro[MAX],Nome_livro;
        printf("Insira o nome do livro a eliminar");
        fgets(cadas_livro[i].Nome_livro,20,stdin);
        for(i=0;i<=MAX;i++)
        {
            if(cadas_livro[i]==Nome_livro)
            cadas_livro[i].isbn=cadas_livro[i+1];
            else
            printf("Livro nao encontrado\n");
        }
}
```

Comment: bem vindo ao StackOverflow, você pode acessar esse link, **[Como fazer uma boa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**, para saber como se deve organizar sua pergunta, depois clique em **[Editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/138360/edit)** para fazer as mudanças necessárias.

Comment: Você está usando um vetor de livros, que não é dinâmico. O que imagina para representar um livro excluído? Um campo excluído? Zerar as informações da posição?

Comment: Na verdade eu pretendo criar uma função que da a possibilidade de apagar um livro armazenado no vetor

Comment: Apenas quero criar uma função deletar

Comment: A resposta postada resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução apresentada foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que ela é satisfatória. Também pode votar em toda e qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos). Aceitar e votar são coisas distintas.

Answer (score 2):

Esse código tem diversos outros erros, então nem tentei testar. Isso responde a pergunta, mas não faz o código funcionar. É mais ou menos isto aqui:

```
void eliminar() { //o certo é receber o array como parâmetro
    Livro cadas_livro[MAX]; //isto está bem errado, em todas funções
    char Nome_livro[20];
    printf("Insira o nome do livro a eliminar");
    fgets(Nome_livro, 20, stdin);
    for (int i = 0; i <= MAX; i++) { //MAX não vai dar certo se o número é variável
        if (strcmp(cadas_livro[i].Nome_livro, Nome_livro)) {
            for (int j = i; j <= MAX; j++) { //precisa "puxar" todos os seguintes
                cadas_livro[j] = cadas_livro[j + 1];
            }
        } else printf("Livro nao encontrado\n");
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/DeleteItem.c).

Comment: gostaria apenas que me ajuda-se a construir a função,estou aprendendo agora